# How to remove an anonymous function bound by addEventListener with an event object as argument

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
    if(ev.ctrlKey)dosomething();
},false);
```

Is there any way to remove the anonymous function?

Comment: If you use the lazy style, like: `document.onkeyup = function(){}`, then you can just do like: `document.onkeyup = undefined;`.

Comment: Does it have to stay anonymous?

Answer (score 1):

You can write yourself a little interface to `addEventListener`, as follows:

```
function addEventListener(elt, event, fn) {
  elt.addEventListener(event, fn);
  return function() {
    elt.removeEventListener(event, fn);
  };
}
```

This returns a function which can be used to remove the event listener, whatever function was passed.

To use this:

```
var remove = addEventListener(body, 'click', () => alert('Hi Mom'));

remove();
```

To remove the event listener immediately after it fires, then you just need:

```
function addEventListenerOnce(elt, event, fn) {
  elt.addEventListener(event, function listener() {
    fn(e);
    elt.removeEventListener(elt, listener);
  });
}
```

Or, you could use the new `{once: true}` option which is being implemented in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can name an anonymous function and use that to unbind it

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',function handleKeyUp(ev){
    document.removeEventListener(ev.type, handleKeyUp);
    if(ev.ctrlKey)dosomething();
},false);
```

Comment: While this works, the function is no longer *anonymous*. It now has a name.

Comment: This definitely wins the prize for oxymoron of the day.

Comment: Cool story. Still the most sane way to handle OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arrow function to call the function AND pass through the event.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup',event => dosomething(event));
function dosomething(event){
    console.log("Test 1");
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee.caller);
}

/////////////////////////////////////
//OR
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    console.log("Test 2");
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
});
```

Using this implementation also allows you to retain the scope of `this`.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Makyen ahhhhh I thought he was talking about removing the anonymous function (syntax) - not the actual event... ???

Comment: @Makyen please see improved post. - I agree - I originally misread the post.

Comment: @Makyen damn - you know how to make a man work... please see updated answer.

Comment: I would suggest you use a form similar to what the OP did (i.e.with the `if(ev.ctrlKey)dosomething();`) Using `=>` does not matter (i.e. works with `=>` and `function`). Actually, re-reading the Question removing it in `dosomething()` is OK, but I would also show doing so in the main function (unclear if either is acceptable to the OP). In the primary handler, it would just be `arguments.callee` (which works). The OP is not clear if he wants to be able to remove it outside of the handler, so you might want to touch on that not being possible.

Comment: @Makyen The question is very vague... If he shows interest, I will update this again - cheers.

Comment: *Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of `arguments.callee()` in strict mode. Avoid using `arguments.callee()` by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove only that event listener from *outside* the listener function while having the function remain *anonymous*. While it might appear anonymous in your code, it is assigned to a variable, of some sort, which effectively names it, even if the name is `listeners.keyup[3]`.

You can remove the event listener from within the event listener itself by using [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)<sup>1</sup>, or from a function which it calls (as mentioned in [Zze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40668423/3773011)).

To remove a listener using [`EventTarget.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), you need a reference to the actual function which is listening. You will need to do one of:

- Name the function.

  ```js
  document.addEventListener('keyup',handleKeyupEvent,false);

  function handleKeyupEvent(ev) {
      if(ev.ctrlKey) {
          dosomething();
      } else {
          console.log('keyup event, no Ctrl key');
      }
  }

  function dosomething(){
      console.log('Ctrl key');
      document.removeEventListener('keyup',handleKeyupEvent,false);
  }
  ```
- Assign it to a variable, which is effectively naming it.
  The variable does not have to be just a variable that refers only to the function (e.g. `handleKeyupEvent`). For instance, you could store a list of your listeners in an Object, or Array (e.g. `listeners.keyup[3]`). This can be advantageous when the actual listener function is dynamically created (e.g. with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

  ```js
  handleKeyupEvent = function(ev) {
      if(ev.ctrlKey) {
          dosomething();
      } else {
          console.log('keyup event, no Ctrl key');
      }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keyup',handleKeyupEvent,false);

  function dosomething(){
      console.log('Ctrl key');
      document.removeEventListener('keyup',handleKeyupEvent,false);
  }
  ```
- Access it from within the listener using [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)<sup>1</sup>

  ```js
    
      document.addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
      if(ev.ctrlKey) {
          dosomething();
          ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, arguments.callee,false);
      } else {
          console.log('keyup event, no Ctrl key');
      }
  },false);

  function dosomething(){
      console.log('Ctrl key');
  }
  ```
- Access it from a function the listener calls using [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

  ```js
      document.addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
      if(ev.ctrlKey) {
          dosomething(ev);
      } else {
          console.log('keyup event, no Ctrl key');
      }
  },false);

  function dosomething(ev){
      console.log('Ctrl key');
      ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener(ev.type, dosomething.caller,false);
  }
  ```
- In some other way, store a reference to the function.

  - Store it in a closure (see [torazaburo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40669940/3773011) for one way).

### Removing all listeners on an element

For a regular element (i.e. not `<document>`, etc.), you can effectively remove *all* listeners, but no just one.  You could sufficiently manipulate the DOM such as to remove all event listeners on that element (or make an equivalent clone of the element). The least disruptive would be to [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the element and then replace the current element with the clone while appending all the children of the original to the clone (thus keeping any event handlers that exist on the children and their descendants).

---

1. [MDN has this to say about using `arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee#Description):

> Warning: The [5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) forbids use of `arguments.callee()` in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). Avoid using `arguments.callee()` by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself.

Basically, it is better to just give the function a name, even if it is just valid within that function expression:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup',function myFunctionName(ev){
    //myFunctionName is only valid within the function. You should use this type of
    //  name instead of using arguments.callee.
    if(ev.ctrlKey)dosomething();
},false);
```