# Chrome extension How to remove a Listener on chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

i am trying to remove this Listener in a google chrome extension for blocking urls, but i don't know how!

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
              function(info) {
                console.log("Chat intercepted: " + info.url);
                return {cancel: true}; },
                {urls: ["https://sampleUrl/*"]},
                ["blocking"]
    );
```

Comment: Effectively identical with good answers, but not a valid dup target: [How to remove an anonymous function bound by addEventListener with an event object as argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40668396/3773011)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to create a named function instead of an anonymous function

```
var myfunction= function (info) {
  //Instructions 
  return {cancel: true}; };
```

and replace it as a variable in the code :

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
                 myfunction,
                {urls: ["https://sampleUrl/*"]},
                ["blocking"]
    );
```

if i want to remove that listener i use :

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(myfunction);
```