# webRequestBlocking - URL glob pattern not matched in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, webrequest

I've noticed that my url patterns are not matched by webRequestBlocking in firefox while working fine in chrome. In my code when the url to block is added to the database, I will add a glob `*` after the path to let the interested site and all pages blocked if the user try to visit it. What is happening is that if the website is blocked, the homepage will be not accessible, but all the links will works correctly and this isn't what I want. As I wrote, this happens only on firefox. How I can solve this to prevent blocked sites navigation?

**background.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import db from './database';

let blacklist = [];

db.find({}, (err, data) => {
  if( data.length > 0 ){
    data.forEach( (item) => {
      blacklist.push(item.siteUrl);
    })
  }
});

const menu = browser.contextMenus.create({
  type: "normal",
  title: browser.i18n.getMessage("extName"),
  contexts: ["all"],
  visible: true
});

const addToBlacklist = (details) => {
// siteUrl will look like: https://www.example.com/*
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.findOne({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    if( !data ){
      db.insert({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
        console.log(`Website ${data.siteUrl} added to blacklist`);
        blacklist.push(data.siteUrl);
        browser.tabs.insertCSS({
          file: browser.runtime.getURL("content-replace.css")
        });
      });
    }else{
      return;
    }
  });  
}

const removeFromBlacklist = (details) => {
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.remove({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    blacklist = blacklist.filter( (item) => {
      item !== siteUrl 
    });
    if( !blacklist ){
      browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
    }else{
      browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: blacklist },["blocking"]);
    }
    console.log(`Website ${siteUrl} removed from blacklist`);
    browser.tabs.reload({ bypassCache: true });
  });
  console.log(blacklist);
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( (details) => {
  var isBlocked = blacklist.includes(details.url);
  console.log(isBlocked);
  return { cancel: isBlocked }
},{
  urls: ["<all_urls>"], 
  types: ["main_frame"]
},["blocking"]);
```

**UPDATE**
I've investigated a bit and I've discovered that the problem will happening also in chrome, this because the check method I'm using `includes(details.url)` will only consider the host and not the paths of the domains blocked. This means that if the user block the `https://www.example.com/` and then navigate to `https://www.example.com/onepage` the path will cause that the `isBlocked` var is set on false and the requests to the website aren't blocked. Can anyone suggest me a fix please?

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested in the comments, I've registered an event listener for `webRequest` when the blacklist is loaded from the database. When the sites are added to the blacklist all seems working fine but the problems starts now when I need to remove an url from the blacklist. The removed website will remain blocked also if the blacklist array is updated, I suspect that there is something wrong in my logics:

```
let blacklist = [];

const blockRequests = (details) => {
  console.log(details);
  return { cancel: true }
}

db.find({}, (err, data) => {
  if( data.length > 0 ){
    data.forEach( (item) => {
      blacklist.push(item.siteUrl);
    });
    browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: blacklist },["blocking"]);
  }
});

const addToBlacklist = (details) => {
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.findOne({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    if( !data ){
      db.insert({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
        console.log(`Website ${data.siteUrl} added to blacklist`);
        blacklist.push(data.siteUrl);
        browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
        browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: blacklist },["blocking"]);
        browser.tabs.insertCSS({
          file: browser.runtime.getURL("content-replace.css")
        });
      });
    }else{
      return;
    }
  });  
}

const removeFromBlacklist = (details) => {
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.remove({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    blacklist = blacklist.filter( (item) => {
      item !== siteUrl 
    });
    console.log(blacklist);
    if( !blacklist ){
      browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
    }
    console.log(`Website ${siteUrl} removed from blacklist`);
    browser.tabs.reload({ bypassCache: true });
  });
}
```

Comment: The fragment of code seems fine so you need to debug the problem, look at those urls, check the blacklist is correct, and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, the blacklist is correct, I've done a `console.log()` and the urls are saved with the glob `*` at the end as expected, I want to try by cleaning the browser cache. I've encountered the problem by selecting an url of a blocked website that was in the history, maybe can be this the problem ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser.

Comment: yes, I think it's a firefox bug, I'm using the developer edition v80, but need to test on the normal release v79

Comment: @wOxxOm I've investigated about the strange issue, it seems that the includes will look for the exact matching of the url, this will prevent the `isBlocked` var to be set as true if a page of a blocked domain is visited, also if the glob is set into the url. Is there a better check I can use?

Comment: It's best to re-register the listener using a url filter, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925898/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220341/discussion-between-nukiko12-and-woxxom).

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, I need to try, but initially the blacklist is empty so I can't register the event listener for the requests?

Comment: The example I've linked already accounts for that, please take a look.

Comment: @wOxxOm just the last thing I get this error when an url is removed from the blacklist `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type error for parameter filter (Error processing urls: Array requires at least 1 items; you have 0) for webRequest.onBeforeRequest` this is normal because the array is empty, but it's a problem because I need to take care also of this

Comment: When the array is empty you should only unregister the old listener. My example already accounts for that.

Comment: @wOxxOm look at the question update, I have some trouble about event listeners. If I remove a website, the block still remain also if the array is updated.

Comment: You need to re-register the listener every time the list is changed (added or removed).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, worked like charm after your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of wOxxOm that linked me an interesting question, I've solved the problem with small modifications to my code, I will post them so other peoples can benefit of them in case of they have the same problem:

```
let blacklist = [];

const blockRequests = (details) => {
  console.log(details);
  return { cancel: true }
}

db.find({}, (err, data) => {
  if( data.length > 0 ){
    data.forEach( (item) => {
      blacklist.push(item.siteUrl);
    });
// registering the webRequest listener if blacklist array is not empty
    browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: blacklist },["blocking"]);
  }
});

// this function is called when user click a context menu voice
const addToBlacklist = (details) => {
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.findOne({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    if( !data ){
      db.insert({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
        console.log(`Website ${data.siteUrl} added to blacklist`);
        blacklist.push(data.siteUrl);
// removing the old listener
        browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
// registering the new one
        browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: blacklist },["blocking"]);
        browser.tabs.insertCSS({
          file: browser.runtime.getURL("content-replace.css")
        });
      });
    }else{
      return;
    }
  });  
}


const removeFromBlacklist = (details) => {
  let siteUrl = `${details.pageUrl}*`;
  db.remove({ siteUrl }, (err, data) => {
    blacklist = blacklist.filter( (item) => {
      return item !== siteUrl 
    });
    if( blacklist.length > 0 ){
     browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
     browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockRequests, { urls: 
blacklist },["blocking"]);
    }else{
    browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener( blockRequests );
    }
    browser.tabs.reload({ bypassCache: true });
  });
}
```