# webRequest is not working with https://www.youtube.com/?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I have an array of URLs in local storage, and I am trying to block those. All URLs except `https://www.youtube.com/` are blocked successfully.
Even when refreshing the page in case of `https://www.youtube.com/`, it is logging to the console "entered" that is inside the `if` statement of blockListener.
then even after this is not blocking the request.

Why is happening so?

code is here.......

```
    function blockListener(details) {  
            var sites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(sitesToBeBlockedKey));//got sites array
            console.log(sites.includes(details.url));
            if(sites.includes(details.url)){
                console.log('entered');
                return {
                    cancel: true
                };
            }else{
                return {
                    cancel: false
                };
            }
    }

    
    function checkBlockRequest(){
                console.log('blocking start');
                chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( blockListener, { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: [ 'main_frame' ] }, ['blocking'] );
        });
    }

    checkBlockRequest();//called
```

Comment: Open `chrome://apps` and remove YouTube app, which doesn't do anything useful anyway, then reload your extension. Also, consider using declarativeNetRequest as it's much faster.

Comment: @wOxxOm it didn't work for me. I had removed youtube app then reloaded extension but it is still not blocked. 
But if there is any influence of the apps for being in `chrome://apps` then why `google drive` is blocked even it is inside `chrome://apps` . I think the main issue is something else...

Comment: Try reworking your code as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925898). You will probably need to add `*` to each URL in the storage first. The difference is that webRequest will perform matching of the URLs internally.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hey I try to debug my code several times and finally i come to a thing i don't know why was happening this thing.
So the basically , i have seen that i was trying to block requests having `type: main_frame`
But when i had observed the `details` of the [link](https://www.youtube.com/) ,the type of this request was `script`. I never heard about `type: script` but then what i have done is that i have removed `types:[....]` key from the filter and things are now fine. Now i am able to block all urls i want.
I had also seen the `type: ping or image or script` for some othe urls conti....

Comment: But i don't have any idea about them.
Can you please help me to get the issue clear for my understanding?